# Push provisioning API (TapAndPay lib) return Calling package not verified

Tags: android, android-tap-and-pay

I am implementing add a card to google pay. I download the demo project and install the demo app. And I basically copy code from that demo to my project but almost all functions return the error `Calling package not verified`. I can not find anything for package verifies.

**UPDATE (probable solution):**

I found how to generate SHA-256 key in doc.

```
# Function to display your SHA-256
$ keytool -printcert -jarfile my-push-provisioning-app.apk | grep SHA256
```

and send the result of this command to google via the [form](https://support.google.com/faqs/contact/pp_api_allowlist?authuser=1) in doc...
I did it and now I am waiting for some response. It could take them 2 weeks...

I am just wondering if they send me an acceptance email or if it just starts work ...

Comment: i have same issue , and i already did what you mentioned above .
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 15009: Calling package not verified

Comment: you have to fill one of that forms in doc and send it to google they will need to have your package name "com.company.myawesomeapp" and then it will work

Comment: I've done this before , what is strange here is that there are devices that this error appears, and there are devices that it does not appear.

Comment: @LukášŠálek did it worked for you after submitting the form?

Comment: @RakshitSoni yes it works

Comment: If I get this error (15009)  if I'm running the app on an emulator, on a device it's fine

Answer (score 6):

ok for someone that is encountering this issue... hope this help someone

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 15009: Calling package not verified
```

the 15009 is an error
https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/support/troubleshooting#debugging_tapandpay_unavailable_15009_errors

basically what it says , the apk build you have is not whitelisted push provisioning at google

you need to request a form to allow to whitelist it

what you need is get your SHA-256 of your key
and request it to allow, follow the link below for more info:
https://developers.google.com/pay/issuers/apis/push-provisioning/android/allowlist#allowlisting_internal_builds_of_your_app

if your build is in playstore or google console, the fingerprint can be grab automatically by them so no need to request ....but if you have a apk build that is created from a CI Pipeline that uses an upload key not app signing key , then you had to manually request it using the Sha-256 of upload key

this is why for the commenter above the release build work for them
because it gets the SHa-256 from google console (App signing key) automatically

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was:

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 15009: Calling package not verified
```

I've realized that it only reproduced on the `debug` build type. After I switched to `release`, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

2 points for debug env:

- provide to google your SHA-256 of your key (wrote above)
- add special file to downloads to switch on sandbox mode

> adb shell touch /sdcard/Download/android_pay_env_override_sandbox